# Retrieving an Email folder using ANT

Tags: deployment, ant, migration-tool, folder

Can anyone post the correct XML for retrieving an Email folder using ANT?

Thx.

Answer (score 2):

Email template can't be fetched with wildcard as we can do for other component so you need to specify the folder name in which you have your email template

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Package xmlns="http://soap.sforce.com/2006/04/metadata">
  <types>
   <members>unfiled$public/EMAILTEMPLATENAME</members>
   <members>EmailTemplates/EMAILTEMPLATENAME</members>             
   <name>EmailTemplate</name>
  </types>
 <version>28.0</version>
</Package>
```

it may be a tedious task to read all email template name and create package.xml out of it so for that purpose you can use eclipse IDE to generate package.xml for you

[image]

[image]

after completing both steps you can copy package.xml in your ant folder.

Comment: I know how to retrieve the templates, what I am struggling with is the Folder itself.  I have created a new folder with 4 new templates, and the retrieval of the template is working fine, but the folder is not being retrieved.  That is leading to a deployment failure because I am trying to deploy templates to a non-existent folder.  Thx.

Comment: you need to create folder in your target org first. that is the manual process